# Reading serilog logs directly from the console

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, filebeat

I'm using serilog to write .NET application's logs to console and I want to read those log from application's console with Filebeat and send them to elasticsearch, is it possible?

Comment: Why take the detour?

Comment: I just wondered :)

Comment: Well, it would probably be more robust if you just used the appropriate sink directly. Is there a particular reason you want it that way?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to just use this with serilog:

https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch